# PHP - if last number in string is equal to 9 do something

Tags: php

If I have a string in php and I need to do something if the last digit equals 9 how can I do it? For example,

```
$cost = '23829';
TRUE
```

or

```
   $cost = '2382';
   FALSE
```

or

```
   $cost = '9';
   TRUE
```

or

```
 $cost = '9999998';
   FALSE
```

Basically if the last number is 9 times original number by 2, I tried the following methods but they do not work.

```
 $cost = strrev($cost);
   if ($cost[0] == 9) $cost = strrev($cost) * 2;
```

and

```
if (substr($cost, -1) === '9') .......
```

They do not work as expected.

Comment: Do a var_dump of `$cost = strrev($cost); var_Dump($cost[0]);`, or `var_dump( (substr($cost, -1) );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try either:

```
if (substr($cost, -1) == 9) .......
```

or:

```
if ( (int) substr($cost, -1) === 9) .......
```

Comment: Does the latter line really work? `(int)` and `=== '9'` does not match its type.

Comment: There was no `'9'` but `9`. Or you mean his example? But there's no `(int)`

Comment: Thanks, the first works fine :), had me stumped for awhile cheers

Comment: No problem, but the funny thing is that it's impossible for that one to work, and for your examples to don't! They're similar, I was just about to delete my answer actually :) probably $cost is not a string but an integer in the first place.